# Determining font used in image or close alternative

Tags: fonts, logo, text

Can anyone help me identify the font used in this logo?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [WhatTheFont!](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) or asking in the [Identify this Font Subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/identifythisfont)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Logo was probably inspired by [Cipher font](http://www.dafont.com/cipher.font?text=George). They added a lachrymal ear (in yellow) to the 'g' in the logotype much like Georgia or Baskerville.

[image]